# Is it possible to limit body size by content in Nginx

Tags: validation, nginx

Nginx provides the [client_max_body_size](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) directive, which limits max body size by checking the “Content-Length” request header. Is it possible to pass this limit by setting custom content-length? And is it possible to limit additionally by real content length (but without loading more content than the limit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that:
1. when I set custom content-length Nginx will believe it but it will load only that much data from the request body;
2. as a consequence there is no sense to limit by body additionally.